# How to do something when a python object is destroyed?

Tags: python

How can I perform some cleanup action when a python object is destroyed (for any reason)?

Comment: `def __del__(self):`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extend the class of the object:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __del__(self):
        object.__del__(self)
        dosomething()
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this fire when I kill the script (I think a 'finally' would in that situation?)?

Comment: What do you mean killing the script? Don't you mean destroying the object?

Comment: I want to clean up even if I CTRL-C the script, i.e. so both when the object is destroyed naturally by the GC and also following a SIGTERM.

Comment: Ctrl-C doesn't destroy an object.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you read this: [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)
and think really hard if `__del__` will do what you want as most likely it will not... due to peculiar nature of garbage collection.

If you really need to release a resource I recommend using [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) and `with` statement.

Comment: @jbrown yes, unless you use SIGKILL - but with SIGKILL you can't clean up anyway. __del__ is equaly reliable in killing context but not so much when it comes to continues operation as it may not get called when you expect it to be called - e.g. it can be called much later than you would expect it to be called